# Joining CSV to feature class in oracle dB and writing out matched records to feature class in file geodatabase on local machine using FME

Tags: file-geodatabase, fme-form, fme-transformer

I'm currently using a CSV reader, Database Joiner and ESRI Geodatabase Writer. The join is working perfectly:

[image]

But when I connect the joined output to the geodatabase writer no records are written to the feature class in the file gdb and I get an error saying "Cannot write a non-area feature to an area feature class":[image]

I have tried both Drop and Create and Truncate Existing for Table Handling.
[image]

Comment: does your csv have any coordinates like lat/lng? or are you joining by id? I would use the FeatureReader (or at least try it) http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/featurereader.htm

Answer (score 2):

The error states that you are creating a feature class for polygons, but are writing no geometry.

So that gives us a few options to consider:

- If you truly don't want geometry in the feature class, then in the feature type dialog (the screenshot you posted) change the geometry type setting (it would be something like geodb_none).

But if you do want geometry, where is that geometry coming from?

- If the geometry is meant to come from the CSV file, then you need to somehow convert it from text to points to areas. The transformers that would help are the VertexCreator and the LineBuilder.
- If the geometry is meant to come from the database, then you'll have to use a different transformer to the DatabaseJoiner. That transformer only returns attributes, not geometry. As mentioned in a comment, the FeatureReader is your friend there. It will read a record from the database for each incoming FME feature, and that can include the geometry of that record.

I hope this helps. If not, please do let us know.

Comment: Thanks Mark! This definitely helped I was in fact not writing any geometry. FeatureJoiner ended up producing the desired result.